# Drop-on functionality in table in Shiny

Tags: r, jquery-ui, shiny, shinyjs, shinyjqui

I am searching for a method (package) that enables me to 'drop' a row from one table **on** a row in another table. The server-side functionality that I am envisioning with it is that I can create some logic that will update the destination table. Unfortunately, I have not been successful prototyping this with the packages with the available shiny packages I could find.

The idea of the MVP concept in the code below is to assign (with *drag 'n drop on*) one of the callers in the top table to a row in the second table.

The closes I have come to it, is the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("UI functionality: Drop-on table"),
  h3("Callers - (source)"),
  tableOutput("callers"),
  h3("Calls to be made - (destination)"),
  tableOutput("calls_to_be_made"),
  hr()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  callers <- tibble(
    Caller = c("Jerry", "Donald")
  )
  
  calls_to_be_made <- tibble(
    Name = c("John", "Fred", "Bill", "Freddy"),
    PhoneNumber = c("0123 456 785", "0123 456 6453", "9876 532 432","235 63 430"),
    Caller = c("Jerry",NA,NA,NA )
  )
  
  jqui_sortable(
    ui      = "#callers table",
    options = list(items = "tbody tr", connectWith = "#calls_to_be_made table")
  )

  jqui_sortable(
    ui      = "#calls_to_be_made table",
    options = list(items = "tbody tr")
  )

  output$callers <-  renderTable(callers, rownames = T)
  output$calls_to_be_made <-  renderTable(calls_to_be_made, rownames = T)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have tried solutions with the `shinyjqui` functions `jqui_draggable()` and `jqui_droppable()` but those attempts didn't work out and I have the feeling that they were actually further away from what the code above sketches.

I am looking for creative ideas and suggestions to implement this functionality. Hopefully some of you who read this question will have create suggestions of accomplishing this functionality in shiny.

Comment: There is no server-side functionality that will do this.  This will be Client Side only, such as with JavaScript or jQuery. I have never used shiny, so I am making guesses, but I suspect it adds header and script details for Drag, drop, sortable, as needed or setup in your server-side script. You will want to look at the resulting HTML to examine the coding that's output.

Comment: @Twisty: You are absolutely right the UI interaction will be client side, but it will have to be closely conneceted with Shiny's server-side logic.

Comment: @Jochen It's not clear if you need Drag & Drop or just Sortable. Do you want to move items back and forth or just one way? That's really the difference. Is shiny throwing any errors when you build the page?

Comment: @Twisty: The above code is working fine for adding a row from the first table (Callers) to the second (Calls to be made); no errors on the shiny side. It places it in between. I am looking for a 'drop on' a specific row. Thus, assigning a call to a specific caller.  I want to capture caller Jerry is assigned to make the call to Bill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an interface using `{shinyjqui}` that allows you to drag cells from some
table, drop them into a different table, and have shiny update the
underlying data frame of the table the draggable was dropped in.

First we need to define our draggable and droppable in our server function.

```r
  jqui_draggable(
    ui = "#callers td",
    options = list(
      revert = "invalid",
      helper = "clone"))
  
  droppable <- function() {
    jqui_droppable(
      ui = "#calls_to_be_made td",
      options = list(
        drop = JS("function(event, ui) {
                     Shiny.setInputValue(\"update_cells\", {
                       source_col: ui.draggable.index(),
                       source_row: ui.draggable.parent().index() + 1,
                       dest_col: $(this).index(),
                       dest_row: $(this).parent().index() + 1
                     });
                   }")))
  }

  droppable() #Initialisation
```

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, the
`jqui_droppable` call is encapsulated in a function (`droppable`),
because we need to call it again later.

Second, we use
`Shiny.setInputValue()` (a javascript function) to send the row- and
column indices of the cell that was dropped (`source_*`) and the cell that
was dropped on (`dest_*`) to the shiny backend. Javascript indices start
at 0 and R indices at 1, so we offset the JS ones to match the
internal R ones. However, because rownames take up a column in the
HTML table, but not in the R data frame, we do not need to offset the column indices.

Next we make `calls_to_be_made` reactive and write the logic that
updates the data frame server side.

```r
  calls_to_be_made_react <- reactiveVal(calls_to_be_made)

  observeEvent(input$update_cells, {
    ## Update dataset
    if (min(unlist(input$update_cells)) > 0) {
      updated_ctbm <- calls_to_be_made_react()
      ## Specify what row and column to drop in
      updated_ctbm[
        input$update_cells[["dest_row"]],
        "Caller"] <- callers[
          input$update_cells[["source_row"]],
          input$update_cells[["source_col"]]]
      
      calls_to_be_made_react(updated_ctbm)

      ## Make sure the newly drawn table becomes droppable again
      droppable()
    }
  })
```

The condition in the if-statement checks if rownames are being dragged & dropped and does not update the data frame when that is the
case. This condition could be extended to some sort of validation
function that limits what cells can be dropped on by which draggable cell, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Inside the `observableEvent` is also where we call our `droppable`
function again. Because shiny redraws the entire table, the code that
makes that table droppable needs to be run again as well.

Lastly we need to update the output call, so it uses the reactive
`calls_to_be_made`.

```r
  output$calls_to_be_made <-  renderTable(calls_to_be_made_react(), rownames = T)
```

This gives the following server function that does what you are asking for.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  callers <- tibble(
    Caller = c("Jerry", "Donald")
  )

  calls_to_be_made <- tibble(
    Name = c("John", "Fred", "Bill", "Freddy"),
    PhoneNumber = c("0123 456 785", "0123 456 6453", "9876 532 432","235 63 430"),
    Caller = c("Jerry",NA,NA,NA )
  )

  jqui_draggable(
    ui = "#callers td",
    options = list(
      revert = "invalid",
      helper = "clone"))
  
  droppable <- function() {
    jqui_droppable(
      ui = "#calls_to_be_made td",
      options = list(
        drop = JS("function(event, ui) {
                     Shiny.setInputValue(\"update_cells\", {
                       source_col: ui.draggable.index(),
                       source_row: ui.draggable.parent().index() + 1,
                       dest_col: $(this).index()
                       dest_row: $(this).parent().index() + 1
                     });
                   }")))
  }

  droppable() #Initialisation

  calls_to_be_made_react <- reactiveVal(calls_to_be_made)

  observeEvent(input$update_cells, {
    ## Update dataset
    if (min(unlist(input$update_cells)) > 0) {
      updated_ctbm <- calls_to_be_made_react()
      ## Specify what row and column to drop in
      updated_ctbm[
        input$update_cells[["dest_row"]],
        "Caller"] <- callers[
          input$update_cells[["source_row"]],
          input$update_cells[["source_col"]]]
      
      calls_to_be_made_react(updated_ctbm)

      ## Make sure the newly drawn table becomes droppable again
      droppable()
    }
  })
  
  output$callers <-  renderTable(callers, rownames = T)
  output$calls_to_be_made <-  renderTable(calls_to_be_made_react(), rownames = T)
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. Great answer!